# Why object doesn't emit light?

Tags: materials, light, lighting, world

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByNnpN_64Z8). Rechecked, but still no light on a surface from emitting object. 
Here is properties of the emitting object and the world:
[image]
[image]

Comment: i might sound off topic but you shouldnt really be using blender internal render. Use cycles instead. way simpler and accurate

Comment: @Ashok you right, it works, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new project and it works now, seems to be just Blender's glitch.

Answer (score -1):

Try unchecking Indirect lighting and set Gather to Raytrace.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/65810)

Comment: @batFINGER: I made it simple for you. You happy?

Comment: And is batFINGER a human or some crude bot? It sounds like one. I DIDN'T ask for clarification.

Comment: The message above is generated by review.  I  didn't downvote.  Your answer came up as ["Low Quality in the review"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/65810) IMO it's borderline, I went the way of delete as it could be a comment, _Try_ A or B... rather than A does this B does that to give the result you want.   Others need to vote for it to be a _fate  de compli_ .. oh and is _crude human_ an option.

Comment: Lukasz, I just tried what I was trying to do works now somehow, I created new project, probably it was Blender's glitch. Your solution gives emitting light on another object but it loses color of the emitter (just white light). (I didn't downvote either)