# How to find and delete similar mesh

Tags: mesh

I have created a model and accidentally it overlap 3 times. How can i delete the overlap or duplicate mesh that created accidentally and get my single piece model. I tried <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> --> object Data but cant find. Manually deleting takes much time.

[image]

Any addon or way to delete the duplicate model overlap 3 times. Suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: I guess you need to do it manually. Note that you can use alt + right click to display a Select Menu that will allow to see what object is available on the position of your cursor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Cleaning unwanted overlapping duplicate meshes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/87489/12947)

Comment: @unutbu cheers on digging that one up, had forgotten completely. (have also discovered `zip` since.). ... same OP too... two bad memories lol.

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>**RMB** 🖱</kbd> on your object and:

1. Rename (outliner) the selected object to keep it;
2. In the Select menu click **Select pattern**;

[image]

3. Type in the object name **without numbers**,  followed by an asterisk. E.g. Cube* This selects all the duplicates;
4. Delete selected.

What you type in is a regular expression

Comment: Need to rename **every** object to save which was derived from "Cube" (body wipers lights mudguards ... ) before selecting and deleting.  Similarly for "Cylinder" etc, pretty much  renaming all objects   to save.

Comment: It's **just ten** parts to rename. Are you so lazy or in so much a hurry? And it's the only reasonable way when you have about a hundred of duplicates. Once I had. And scripts may not always work as expected.

Comment: It is IMO not _"the only reasonable way"_. once you select the objects, can move them to another layer (or hide etc) and very simply trash the rest. No renaming, no select pattern operator for each primitive used.  Are you so attached to being right you cannot see this? [Must it always be a shit fight?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122495/why-object-doesnt-emit-light/122511#comment214185_122511)  You complain about a down-vote, your voting  record is  16 votes, 6 down, in 18 months?  Try not to  plumb the depths of childish & pathetic in reply.